# Converting Decimal to ASCII Character

Tags: ascii, decimal, character

I am trying to convert an decimal number to it's character equivalent.  For example:

int j = 65 // The character equivalent would be 'A'.

Sorry, forgot to specify the language.  I thought I did.  I am using the Cocoa/Object-C.  It is really frustrating.  I have tried the following but it is still not converting correctly.

```
char_num1        = [working_text characterAtIndex:i];   // value = 65               
char_num2         = [working_text characterAtIndex:i+1];    // value =  75
char_num3         = char_num1  + char_num2;         // value = 140                                      
char_str1   = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",char_num3];  // mapped value = 229
char_str2   = [char_str2 stringByAppendingString:char_str1];
```

When char_num1 and char_num2 are added, I get the new ascii decimal value. However, when I try to convert the new decimal value to a character, I do not get the character that is mapped to char_num3.

Comment: what language, platform?

Comment: Welcome aboard Kevin. You will notice that simple questions like this usually get an answer, maybe several, in a matter of minutes. It's a good idea to hang around and see the answers so you can reply to simple queries like "what language?" and more focussed answers can be given. Don't forget to 'accept' an answer by clicking on the big tick/checkmark (but don't do it before all the answers are in).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Convert a character to a number in C:

```
int j = 'A';
```

Convert a number to a character in C:

```
char ch = 65;
```

Convert a character to a number in python:

```
j = ord('A')
```

Convert a number to a character in Python:

```
ch = chr(65)
```

Answer (score 1):

Most languages have a 'char' function, so it would be `Char(j)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what language you're asking about. In Java, this works:

```
int a = 'a';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite often done with "chr" or "char", but some indication of the language / platform would be useful :-)

```
string k = Chr(j);
```